# Comparar duas datas

Tags: java, android, datetime

Tenho duas string contendo datas `dataSalva` e `dataDoDia` e estou querendo saber se a `dataDoDia` e 5 dias maior que a `dataSalva` como faço isto

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date data = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(data);
    Date data_atual = cal.getTime();
    String dataDoDia= dateFormat.format(data_atual);
```

Pego esta `data_completa`e salvo no banco 
Ai quando entro abro o aplicativo quero pegar esta data no banco e comparar com a data do dia , que vou pegar do mesmo jeito da data que já foi salva

```
String dataSalva = banco.get();
```

aqui vou ter a data que ja esta salva
ai depois faço a parte la de cima para pegar a data do dia

ai quero comparar estas duas datas  `dataSalva` e `dataDoDia`

Comment: Posta o o seu código... É melhor, pois teremos mais informações, como o formato da data...

Comment: atualizei la..  ..  .

Comment: `data` é a `dataSalva`? Imagino que `data_atual` seja a `DataATual`. Seu código não bate com a descrição da pergunta. Este código tem alguma relevância? Ou a pergunta está errada?

Comment: eu não tenho codigo , este ai e o formato da minha data

Comment: olha a se ficou mais claro

Comment: Dei uma resposta mas não sei se é o que quer já que não tem maiores informações. Noto que a último edição introduziu um novo nome para a data.

Comment: troquei para não confundir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em geral todo mundo recomenda usar o [JodaTime](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) que é muito melhor que a API original. Mas você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
(DataAtual.getTime() - DataSalva.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) == 5
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/SubtractDateJoda.java).

Agora o Java tem uma API oficial mais moderna que é praticamente a JodaTime.

Comment: Isso ai mesmo que eu tava querendo vlw

Comment: Não entendi bem a primeira parte da resposta. Seria um exemplo do que?

Comment: De nada, eu fui testar depois :)